# Linq to entities optimization

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have the following linq to entities query

```
from p in Products
where p.ProductId==1219
select new
{
    Name = p.ProductName,
    count = (from dc in DiscountCodes
        where dc.ProductId == p.ProductId
        select dc).Count()
}
```

Now the sql that gets generated is (using linqpad)

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 1219
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[ProductName] AS [Name], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [DiscountCode] AS [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[ProductId] = [t0].[ProductId]
    ) AS [count]
FROM [Product] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[ProductId] = @p0
```

This doesn't seem very efficient, especially if I need to start adding more counts on related tables.

Is there a better way to optimize this query?

Thanks

Comment: What is the more efficient way to do that in SQL?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I am not sure, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you've a relation between `DiscountCodes` and `Products` tables. I mean `DiscountCodes` table has `ProductId` ForeignKey

Then this should be better

```
from p in Products
where p.ProductId==1219
select new
{
    Name = p.ProductName,
    Count = p.DiscountCodes.Count,
}
```

Comment: `Count` is a method, not property

Comment: Actually it's a Extension method for the IEnumerable and property for the ICollection

Comment: It's still a method. And actually in this case it's an extension method of `IQueryable`

Comment: I insistent it's a property in the ICollection interface :) and it's OK to call it just like that :)

Comment: Agree, navigation properties has type of `ICollection` :) It's now interesting to me does this property executes immediately, or is it translated to `IQueryable` call..

Comment: I think it's somehow delay that till you need it. and in this situation I think the Queryable provider do that. Anyway I don't know exactly how. Wish you configure it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework creates relationship between parent and child table via their foreign key relation. So in this case below query should work for you.

```
from p in Products
where p.ProductId==1219
select new
{
    Name = p.ProductName,
    count = p.DiscountCodes.Count()
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have relationships setup, this however still generates the same sql. I am just wondering if this is the most optimized sql?